# Add line break in a query (MySqli)

Tags: php, mysqli

What do I do for making som line breaks between the rows?

```
echo "<h1>Resultat: </h1><br>" . $row['resultat']. $row['resultat2']. $row['resultat3'] ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Erm... put some line breaks?

```
$row['resultat']."<br />".$row['resultat2']."...";
```